# No connection available in pool, netstat shows non-zero values in Recv-Q

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, netstat, connection-pool

I have an old Java application working on java 1.6 on Tomcat 6. Due to way how it is set up in the environment, it is hard to do any inner diagnostics - basically I can't touch it so - it is a blackbox.

The app is crashing due to lack of free connections. The limits are set high (max 255 parallel connections) but, even if the number of open connections is like 60, it is still crashing.

Netstat shows that there are a lot of data in recvQ (just an example):

```
tcp    1464      0 localhost:7076 remote-host1:3120 ESTABLISHED
tcp    2512      0 localhost:7611 remote-host2:3120 ESTABLISHED
tcp    6184      0 localhost:4825 remote-host3:3120 ESTABLISHED
```

I couldn't find any useful hints about the case (similar issue is here: https://serverfault.com/questions/672730/no-connection-available-in-pool-netstat-recvq-shows-high-number).

The questions:
1) Why the application is not reading all the data received?
2) Because all the data is not read, another connection is opened to the DB. Am I right?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Add some details about how the app crashes.

Comment: The application was leaking resources in (way-too-) many places. Basically closing everything that was used (created/opened) helped a lot.
Thank you, Luis, for your interest in the topic and supportive hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What the application does with the read data? May be it can't write to disk, it's waiting for other conditions, there's a thread lock, etc.

2) New connections are opened because those ones are still in use regardless of the recvQ.

Regarding the number of connections, you should count half closed connections too, these TCP status mean the connection is still active

> ESTABLISHED
>   FIN_WAIT_1
>   FIN_WAIT_2
>   TIME_WAIT

On Linux:
`netstat -ant | grep -E 'ESTABLISHED|FIN_WAIT_1|FIN_WAIT_2|TIME_WAIT' | sort -k 6,6`

To further troubleshoot it's suggested to get thread and/or heap dumps and analyze them.
[Another case](http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2011/04/database-connection-pooling-and-too-may.html) involving TIME_WAIT.